# NoSuchElementException with Java.Util.Scanner with array

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

I m very new to java and don't know why I'm getting this error when I run below program

**program :** this program basically read no of input N in first line and then scan each number and store it in array **arr** and display it.

range of N is : `0<N<10^6`

input numbers can be long so that I used **long array** in the program.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    long no = sc.nextLong();

    if(no > 1000000 || no < 1)
                 System.exit(0);


    long arr[] = new long [(int)no];


    for(int i=0;i<(int)no;i++) {

        arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
        System.out.println(arr[(int)i]);

    }
}
}
```

input values : [here](http://pastebin.com/abpjy2fd) you find input values

**output :**

**Runtime Errors**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2265)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2225)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:23)
```

**rest of output is** [here](http://pastebin.com/mBLsuGKn)

Answer (score 3):

You are repeatedly calling `nextLong()`, but not testing to see if there is a next long:

```
  for(int i=0;i<(int)no;i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println(arr[(int)i]);
}
```

You need do something like this:

```
   for(int i=0;i<(int)no && sc.hasNextLong();i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
    System.out.println(arr[(int)i]);
}
```

Comment: still i'm not getting all input values
check this out : [link](http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/Fn8U8n)

Comment: @VishalPatel I tested and I had all number, you can controll adding this: System.out.println("Length of no:  "+no);
       for(int i=0;i<(int)no && sc.hasNextLong();i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
        System.out.println(arr[(int)i]);
        }  
        System.out.println("Length of array:    "+arr.length);

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;

class Solution {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        InputStream in;
        // initialize in

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        int[] numbers;

        // You don't need to store long values because int values fall within 0 and 10^6
        try {
            numbers = new int[(scanner.hasNextInt()? scanner.nextInt(): 0)];
        } catch(NegativeArraySizeException nase) {
            numbers = new int[0];
        }

        // we store the limits in variables so that your system doesn't create them repeatedly in each iteration
        for(int i = 0, number, LOW = 0, HIGH = 1000000; scanner.hasNextInt() && i < numbers.length;) {
            number = scanner.nextInt();
            if(number > LOW && number < HIGH) {
                numbers[i] = number;

                // go to next index only if we have a number
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```